# eliminar caracteres especiales en nombres de archivos

Tags: linux, archlinux

IFS='
'
for file in $(ls -p | grep -v /);
do
file=$(echo "$file")
mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/*/ /g' | xargs echo -n | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.*-]/ /g' | xargs echo -n)
done
ls

Answer (score 0):

IFS='
'
for file in $(ls -p | grep -v /);
do
file=$(echo "$file")
mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/*/ /g' | xargs echo -n | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.*-]/ /g' | xargs echo -n)
done
ls

Comment: ¿Esto es el mismo código de la pregunta? Lee [answer] (y [ask]).